# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move with "strncat"

Tags: gcc, valgrind

Having this following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char *a = "abc";
        int len = strlen(a);
        char *b = malloc(len + 1); // + 1 for null byte
        //strncpy(b, a, len) // Does not append null byte
        strncat(b, a, len); //should append null byte
        puts(b);
}
```

and runned as `valgrind ./a.out`:

```
...
==7223== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7223==    at 0x484EBD0: strncat (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7223==    by 0x1091FB: main (in /home/shepherd/inteli/c/test/a.out)
==7223== 
abc
...
```

It says `conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)`. What does it mean and why does `strncat` exhibits it?

Does the program do any UB or is erroneous or why is Valgrind screaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is Valgrind screaming?

`strncat` *appends* to `b`, so it has to know `strlen(b)`, but `b` does not point to a string, `b[0]` is uninitialized. `malloc` returns uninitialized memory.

`strncat` finds the position of a zero byte inside the memory pointed to by `b` to copy the characters from `a`. To find the position of a zero byte in a memory region, it has to read char by char that memory region. Because `b` points to uninitailized memory region, `strncat` reading from it results in the valgrind error you are getting.

> Does the program do any UB or is erroneous

Yes, yes.

Comment: Yes, malloc is uninitizlied, but how else do you want to "create&copy" string to new memory? You have to do malloc (you cannot use stack in function and then return pointer to that stack), so you have no other way then malloc. If you have no other option, why is this UB then?

Comment: `how else do you want to "create&copy" string to new memory?` For example with `memcpy(b, a, len + 1)`. Or a plain loop. Or `strcpy`, but `memcpy` will be faster, you already know the length. Or `strncpy(b, a, len + 1)`, but `memcpy` will be faster.  `why is this UB then?` This is UB because `strncat` function _accesses_ `b[0]`, which is uninitialized.

Comment: "Strncat function accesses b[0]"... But so does `strcpy` and `memcpy`. Why would be wrong accessing uninitialized memory when you want to *initialize* it? This is chicken and egg problem. Of course you have to access uninitialized memory to initialize it. First you get raw/uninitizlied memory from malloc and *then* you initialize it, no matter whether you initialize it with `strcat`, `strcpy` or `memcpy`. All this function initialize previously uninitialized memory. So again, how that could be UB?

Comment: I think "accesses" is a bad choice of words. Let's say it that way: "strncat function _reads_ from b[0]". `But so does strcpy and memcpy` Sure, but they only write to it.  `strncat ` _reads_ from `b[0]`. `hy would be wrong accessing uninitialized memory when you want to initialize it?` Nothing, but there is wrong with reading from it _before_ initializing. `hen you initialize it, no matter whether you initialize it with strcat` `strcat` as `strncat` needs to read from the first pointer to get where the string ends. You can't initialize with pure strcat, you have to write one zero byte yourself

Comment: Fair enough. That makes sense. The question then could be why does `strcat` read from destination `b[0]`, when it is suppose just `write` to it. But that is question rather for implementers of that function

Comment: ? No ,`strcat` is supposed to _append_ to string. In order to append, it has to know where the string ends, in other to know that, it has to read from the memory to determine the position of zero byte. In other words, the first argument of `strcat` has to point to a null-terminated string. In the code you posted, the first argument to `strcat` points to uninitialized memory. `for implementers of that function` Code speaks 1000 words - https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strcat.c . `strlen` _reads_ from dest.